# Shell - Bash script to export data from multiple text files with fine name as header to csv

Tags: bash, shell, csv, sh, export-to-csv

I have 900 text files in my folder " Subj1 " in following format

```
file name 1.txt
file name 2.txt
......
file name 900.txt
```

Each file consists of data arranged in 4 rows and 2 columns

```
667869 667869
580083 580083
316133 316133
9291.5 9291.5
```

i would like to export the data in text file to csv into a table in following format : The output csv file should be in this format

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: I would try `paste -d';' *.txt`

Comment: all the text files have data in them, i want to move data in each file to csv, how could i do it

Comment: What is the Subj1 line showing? Please show the output in case of at least 3 files, with more details.

Comment: @blackpen , Subj1 is a folder name and the same name of folder should be output header and filename1 ... filename 900 are the files in the folder Subj1, in output csv file, all the information pertaining to files in the folder subj1 should be arranged in the format which is mentioned above, i have edited my question please check it

Comment: @mouviciel, i can only paste data from each file ,but i would like to even have a header associated each file

Answer (score 2):

I think that the following would do it. The essential tool `paste`, but the following would also output the file name header line.

```
{ for f in *.txt; do
  /bin/echo -n -e "$f\t"
done
echo
paste *.txt
} > output.csv
```

This assumes that there are no other files ending in .txt in the directory than the source files.

If you want another delimiter, say `;`, replace the `\t` on line 2 by `;` and replace the last line by

```
paste -d ';' *.txt
```

Comment: how should i export  all the data into csv file ?

Comment: what if i have 10 folders in directory  with names subj1,subj2,subj3..subj10 and each folder contains 190 such text files with same naming conventions , how could i have one csv file with for each subj folder ?

Comment: Maybe simplest just to cd into each folder separately and run the script in each? Of course, this is scriptable, too. Could you please post this as a separate question, and mark this one as answered (and an upvote for the answer, please).

Comment: i have run the script in the folder, and its giving me syntax errors, is this the bash script ? : following is the error :  syntax error: unexpected end of file,  syntax error: unexpected token done